# How do I bypass the OSX bootloader screen when booting ubuntu installed on macbook

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro

I am running ubuntu 14.04 (no OSX partition) on a macbook pro, when I boot, I have to hold option and then select my ubuntu partition - which is labelled as windows.

Is there a way to bypass this?